# Parse Twitter Login error

Tags: ios, parse-platform, authentication, swift2, xcode7

Ok, so i was supposed to submit my project to the app store for review today, but I have run into a problem that I know nothing about. 
My `Parse twitter login` was working fine and now, even though I do not remember altering anything, it no longer works. I keep getting this error.

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})
failed to login
```

I am simply using the standard `parse login` with twitter, based off the Parse documentation online. Like i said, I also don't remember changing anything prior to this happening. I have no idea where to begin with this error. Here are my login functions.

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {

        let installation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.addUniqueObject("reload", forKey: "channels")
        installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        installation.saveInBackground()

        self.loadMyStars()

        let heartSwitchState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let skullSwitchState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


        if heartSwitchState.objectForKey("nextTimeHeartCanSend") == nil && skullSwitchState.objectForKey("nextTimeSkullCanSend") == nil {

        heartSwitchState.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "nextTimeHeartCanSend")
        skullSwitchState.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "nextTimeSkullCanSend")

        }


        if (PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user)){
            let twitterUsername = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName

            PFUser.currentUser()?.username = twitterUsername

            PFUser.currentUser()?.saveEventually(nil)




    }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {
        print(error)
        print("failed to login")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like this is a bug in the parse/twitter interface. cf the thread on facebook :https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/914545211986956/